Como resuelvo mi llamada a la API?
Cuestion, estoy en un proyecto con angular 17 reconstruyenco una app mas antigua. Y a la hora de hacer un llamado a la API este por alguna razon utilizar la URL del mismo localhost?? El punto de todo esto es que la solicitud de tipo GET en este caso es correcta la cual tengo en su respectivo servicio. Y ya he hecho otras varias llamadas tambien, Y no se que puede estar produciendo el error.
la respuesta de mi app aparece de esta forma:
Request URL:
http://localhost:4200/detalle-carta/19403851
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
[::1]:4200
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
y la de la app antigua asi:
Request URL:
https://REPECTIVA URL DE LA WEB/19456302
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
190.210.222.189:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
mi llamada desde el componente:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { PosicionService } from '../../../core/services/posicion.service';
import { NavBarComponent } from '../../nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { SideBarComponent } from '../../side-bar/side-bar.component';
import { LowerCasePipe, NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../../core/services/local-storage.service';

import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { CartaPorteDetalle } from '../../../core/models/cartaPorteDetalle';
import { CartaPorteService } from '../../../core/services/cartaPorte.service';
import { UtilsService } from '../../../core/services/utils.service';
import moment from 'moment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalle-carta',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NavBarComponent,
    SideBarComponent,
    NgIf,
    LowerCasePipe,

    MatTableModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './detalle-carta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalle-carta.component.css']
})
export class DetalleCartaComponent implements OnInit {

  carta: CartaPorteDetalle = new CartaPorteDetalle(); 
  userCuit: number = 0;
  public momento = moment;
  
  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router,
    private posicionService: PosicionService,
    private cartaPorteService: CartaPorteService,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    public utilsService: UtilsService
  ) {
    this.momento.locale('es');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const userLogueado = this.localStorageService.getObject('accesoActivo')?.usuario;
    this.userCuit = userLogueado ? userLogueado.cuit : 0;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const nroCarta = params['nroCarta'];
      if (nroCarta) {
        this.posicionService.getHistoriaPorNroOrPatente(nroCarta).subscribe(
          (cartasEnc: CartaPorteDetalle[]) => {
            if (cartasEnc.length === 1) {
              this.carta = cartasEnc[0];
            } else if (cartasEnc.length > 1) {
              // Selección de la carta que coincide con el CUIT del usuario
              const cartaCorrecta = this.userCuit ? cartasEnc.find(c => c.Porte_cuit_entregador === this.userCuit) : null;
              this.carta = cartaCorrecta || cartasEnc[0];
            } else {
              this.utilsService.openDefaultDialog('Aviso')('No existe una carta con ese número');
              this.router.navigate(['/home/buscar-carta']);
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error('Error al cargar los detalles:', error);
            this.utilsService.openDefaultDialog('Error')('Hubo un error al cargar los detalles. Intente nuevamente.');
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }

  getAnalisisAll(analisis: any[]): string {
    return analisis.map((an) => this.cartaPorteService.parseAnalisis(an)).join(', ');
  }
  
}

componente de la app vieja:
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CartaPorteDetalle } from '../../models/cartaPorteDetalle';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/authService';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UtilsService } from 'src/app/services/utilsService';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/services/localStorageService';

import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { constants } from '../../environment/constants';
import { CartaPorteService } from 'src/app/services/cartaPorteService';

import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';


@Component({
    selector: 'detalle-carta',
    templateUrl: './detalleCarta.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./detalleCarta.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
    ]
})
export class DetalleCartaComponent {
    carta: CartaPorteDetalle;
    momento = moment;

    constants = constants;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private utilsService: UtilsService,
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
        private router: Router,
        private location: Location,
        private cartaPorteService: CartaPorteService,
        @Inject('Window') private window: Window
    ) {
        // Configuro moment
        this.momento.locale('es');

        const userLogueado = this.localStorageService.getObject('accesoActivo') ?
            this.localStorageService.getObject('accesoActivo').usuario :
            null;

        // Busco el id del usuario a editar en la ruta
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => this.authService.getHistoriaPorNroOrPatente(params.nroCarta).subscribe(
                (cartasEnc: CartaPorteDetalle[]) => {
                    if (cartasEnc.length === 1) {
                        this.carta = cartasEnc[0];
                    } else if (cartasEnc.length > 1) {
                        const cartaCorrecta = cartasEnc.find(cp => cp.porte_cuit_entregador === userLogueado.cuit);
                        if (cartaCorrecta) {
                            this.carta = cartaCorrecta;
                        } else {
                            this.carta = cartasEnc[0];
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.utilsService.openDefaultDialog('Aviso')('No existe una carta con ese numero');
                        this.router.navigate([`/home/buscar-carta`])
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }

    /** Parsea el array de análisis a string */
    getAnalisisAll = (analisis) => analisis
        .map(an => this.cartaPorteService.parseAnalisis(an))
        .join(', ');

    isDownloading = false;

    onDownloadPdf = (quality) => {
        const fa: any = document.querySelector('#detalle-carta-pdf').cloneNode(true);

        fa.classList.add('detalle-pdf');

        document.body.appendChild(fa);

        html2canvas(
            fa,
            {scale: quality}
        ).then(canvas => {
            let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
            pdf.save(`detalle_${this.carta.porte_nro}.pdf`);
            this.isDownloading = !this.isDownloading;
        })
    }

}

